# How to convert cv::Mat to sensor_msgs::Image::Ptr?

Tags: cv-bridge, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was wondering about how to publish cv:Mat. The tutorial wiki
http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages
didn't give me an answer and following code seems working, but I suppose there are a way to do this
without using old CvBridge interface.

```
        IplImage out_msg = sal_float_image;
        sensor_msgs::CvBridge bridge_;
        sensor_msgs::Image::Ptr saliency_msg = bridge_.cvToImgMsg(&out_msg, "passthrough");

        saliency_img_pub.publish(saliency_msg);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9765/how-to-convert-cv::mat-to-sensor_msgs::image::ptr?/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2011-04-19

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`cv::Mat` by itself does not contain all of the information that `sensor_msgs::Image` does, namely the encoding (e.g. bgr8 vs rgb8) and the header (time stamp and tf frame). So you create a `cv_bridge::CvImage` object to convert:

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

cv_bridge::CvImage out_msg;
out_msg.header   = in_msg->header; // Same timestamp and tf frame as input image
out_msg.encoding = sensor_msgs::image_encodings::TYPE_32FC1; // Or whatever
out_msg.image    = sal_float_image; // Your cv::Mat

saliency_img_pub.publish(out_msg.toImageMsg());
```

It's a little verbose; in the future we could add constructors to `CvImage` to streamline this. Note that forgetting to set the header fields is a common bug when using the old `CvBridge`.

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on 2011-04-22**:
Thanks, this is exactly what I want to know. Need to update wiki?

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2015-12-09**:
Hi, but what if you don't have the input message? what information can you set to the header?